# Multi Boot with Restricted Access to Partitions

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

So what I want to do with my laptop is

Let's say I have a single hard drive on the laptop of 240 GB that's split into 2 sets (Set A & Set B) each containing 3 partitions of 40 GB.

Now I install 2 Operating Systems (say OS-A and OS-B) on 2 partitions (1 from Set A and the other in Set B). I want to separate the drives such that when I'm booted in OS-A from Set A, that OS should not be able to access the partitions in Set B. 
Similarly, if I'm booted in OS-B, it should only be able to access partitions of Set B and not of Set A.

I would like to know if such a thing is possible and under what combinations
Windows-Windows / Windows-Linux

***A separate drive just having the boot loader or the boot sequence or MBR may be done if required to achieve the above output***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define accessing them? You can 'unmount' drives in windows, but that doesn't stop you remapping them again to be able to use them.
The only way I can think of is encrypting the drives separately, and only decrypting the one you want to boot up.

Comment: Or some seriously complex all nonsense

Comment: I'm trying to have 2 systems on 1 laptop, so that nothing I do in Set 1 can affect Set 2 and no virus worm trojan etc can be transferred over. It's the perfect fail safe.

I like your idea of mounting and unmounting the option in windows. But how can I make that work in a Linux environment but? like in Linux I might still be able to touch the Windows OS Drives.

Is there any boot encryption decryption software you are aware of? Like it decrypts the specified drive when the OS is run and encrypts then when OS shut down.?

Comment: @djsmiley2k 

missed to add tag earlier